# PHPUnit Testing Json Always Responds With 404

Tags: json, laravel, phpunit, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to test a few things within Laravel unit testing with my API. I want to be able to test things such as if users are able to succsufully be created, logged in, deleted, etc.. The problem I am facing is that no matter what Json I send to my API, I always get this message from PHPUnit:

> Expected status code xxx but received 404
>
> Failed asserting that false is true

I have been recieveing a 404 error with everythingI try to post it seems like. But what is really no making sense at this point is that even this returns a 404 error:

```
/** @test */
public function 404ErrorMessageCheck()
{
  $response = $this->get('/api/user');

  $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

I wrote the above code to check if it even wants to load at all and apparently it doesn't. I was thinking something may be wrong with my auth headers or something but from my understanding, a 404 message means that it isn't even loading.

Here is one of the things that I was origianlly trying to test:

```
  /** @test */
  function results_get_created_correctly()
  {

    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $token = $user->generateToken();

    $response = $this->withHeaders([
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer' . $token
        ])->json('POST', '/api/results', [
        'FirstName' => FirstName,
        'LastName' => LastName,
        'City' => 'Houston',
        'State' => 'Texas',
    ]);

    $response
      ->assertStatus(201)
      ->assertJson([
        'FirstName' => FirstName,
        'LastName' => LastName,
        'City' => 'Houston',
        'State' => 'Texas',
      ]);

    }
```

Same error with the above code though.

Comment: Is this route defined in your laravel app? This error suggests you haven't defined this yet in your routes file(s)

Comment: @Msencenb Yes, all of my routes are defined